# Finding the Y of a known X of a line segment?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I'm trying to place my hero's feet on a ground made up of line segments.

[image]

If I know the X,Y of points A, B, and C and the X of Hero, how do I find the Y of Hero so that his feet touch the ground (assume X is the middle of the Hero and Y is along the bottom)?  And do I have to do anything differently if he's standing exactly over a point?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple geometry. If you know `A` and `B`'s coordinates, you can figure out the equation describing the line joining the two points. Then knowing the hero's `X` location, you can figure out what the Y point is on the A-B line: http://www.skwirk.com.au/p-c_s-12_u-83_t-151_c-479/two-point-formula/nsw/two-point-formula/coordinate-geometry/linear-equations If he's standing over a point, then obviously that point's `Y` position is the position of the hero's feet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `A` and `B` are two points in a coordinate plane with points `(xA, yA)` and `(xB, yB)` respectively - then the slope of the line between them is simple geometry - delta y/delta x, or `(yB-yA)/(xB-xA)`.  The general form of the line can be given as `y = yA+(yB-yA)/(xB-xA)*(x-xA)`

Comment: Wikipedia entry for [point-slope form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope-intercept_form#Point.E2.80.93slope_form), which is basically what he's using here.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm using here.